# Determine time blocks from multiple concurrent time stamps in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

We have a time tracking system where we start a timer for each project we are working on, then stop when complete. There are many times that we have multiple timers going in the same block of time. for example:

Given three timers:

```
Start Time             | End Time                | Time Spent
10/23/2012 10:15:00 AM | 10/23/2012 10:45:00 AM  | 30
10/23/2012 10:15:00 AM | 10/23/2012 11:15:00 AM  | 60
10/23/2012 11:05:00 AM | 10/23/2012 11:35:00 AM  | 30
```

Both are running at the same time, and if used with our time reporting would amount to 2 hours being counted, even though the times are inside of each other when the valid amount of time spent is 1 hour and 20 minutes.

So I am trying to figure out how to go through the time entries and only count the valid time periods.

Any ideas how to calculate this in PHP?

Comment: Where are these stored? Are they in a database?

Comment: Yes they are stored in a MSSQL database

Comment: And `Time Spent` is a calculated field?

Comment: Yes by comparing the start and end timestamps

Comment: @njk thanks for the formatting help

Comment: @MikeMiller If it's a calculated field, please post the column/table structure that is relevant to calculating it.

Comment: There are not any parts in the database to calculate it, just several php functions, that are used when the timer is stopped. Sorry I misread your previous question.